# Was Mystique seen on TV talking to herself when she was talking to Xavier during his freeze mind trick?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

In *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, near the end of the movie there is a scene where Mystique has

> incapacitated Magneto and was aiming her gun at Trask.

Then Xavier uses his psychic power to have a conversation with her. At this point, all of the cameras in the area are pointed at her, and presumably still recording to broadcasting.

While Xavier is talking to Mystique, are the people watching this on TV only seeing Mystique, seemingly talking to herself?

Comment: We'd have to assume that anyone watching would have in fact seen this happen.  Remember in X-2, Xavier freezes time at the museum yet in the live broadcast being show in the televisions, time is flowing normally.  So, chances are, Xavier is only able to freeze his immediate area, not the whole world.  So based on that, yes, the people watching the broadcast would see Mystique talking to off camera Charles.

Comment: In First Class, when Xavier "freezes" in the CIA hallway, the water fountain can still be seen running. The script for X-2 even has a little gag that went unused where one of the president's aides was pouring water during freeze and is confused why he's all wet when everything resumes.

Comment: @Robert Yes I do recall that scene in the museum. I think it would way too hard for Charles to freeze everyone watching TV. I know his freeze ability does not freeze time or else I would not of asked this

Comment: Ok, so based on my comment, and phantom's comment, the answer to your question would be, 'yes' everyone watching the broadcast would have seen everything that happened and the cameras would still be operational.

Comment: @Robert Can you put that as an answer and I will do the rest

Comment: @Huangism sure thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my comment, and phantom's comment, the answer to your question would be, 'yes' everyone watching the broadcast would have seen everything that happened and the cameras would still be operational.